# The Local Storage on my small leaderboard app isnt working correctly

Tags: javascript

Hi guys I am trying to implement local storage in a little app that I am building but it isn't working. I have been working on it for a long time but I don't know what I am doing wrong so any help would be appreciated.

```
#Javascript

const form = document.querySelector('.form');
const scores = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('scores')) || [];

function saveScore() {
const name = document.querySelector('.fullname').value;
const score = document.querySelector('.thescore').value;
const newScore = {
name,
score,
};
scores.push(newScore);
localStorage.setItem('scores', JSON.stringify(scores));
}

function renderScores() {
const scoreList = document.querySelector('.result-list');
scoreList.innerHTML = '';
scores.forEach((score) => {
const li = document.createElement('li');
li.innerHTML = `${score.name} : ${score.score}`;
scoreList.appendChild(li);
localStorage.setItem('scores', JSON.stringify(scores));
});
}

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
saveScore();
renderScores();
localStorage.setItem('scores', JSON.stringify(scores));
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it isn't working"? Are you getting errors? Is nothing being stored? Is it being stored but nothing is returned with `getItem`?

Comment: Tell more about expected behavior and current scene.

Comment: i can see the key and value are saved and I don't get any errors but when I refresh nothing stays on the page. but if i add a new item I can see everything but I refresh everything is gone

Comment: And it looks wired that you `setItem` inside loop of scores.

Comment: @David630 When do you call `renderScores` ? It looks like this is the only way you render `scores` onto your html. If it is not called when load, it will not render scores after you refesh page, until you click the button.

Comment: @bboat ya its only rendering on the HTML ok so I need to call it when the page loads

Comment: cool thanks now its working :) I called the function at the top of the page